# Teaching-oriented lectureship in a research-oriented university

Tags: research-process, teaching, tenure-track, lecturer

I have been offered a teaching-oriented position in power electronics in a research-intensive university. It is not a tenure-track position. It seems fine considering my career and age at this moment but in the long run, I would like to get involved in research and eventually get tenure-track positions. Therefore, I am wondering whether it is possible to do research from this kind of position. I will be grateful to you if you give some guidance with regards to this situation.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/54253/68109 , https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/105280/68109

Comment: Best ask them - we cannot guess their plans.

Comment: If you do not want to teach, please do not take a teaching position.  Students deserve motivated teachers.

Comment: What field? If you were a linguist, it would be much easier to continue to be involved in corpus linguistics compared to field linguistics research.

Comment: The field is power electronics.

Answer (score 6):

It's conceivable that such a position would leave you enough time and energy to pursue research at some level of intensity, but it's impossible to say in general; the answer will vary by country, research field, university, and specific position.

- Find someone who holds (or has held) this type of position at this university and ask them. Advice from this source is likely to be more disinterested and well-informed than you will get from someone associated with the group offering the position.
- If this is impossible, ask someone associated with the group offering the position.